# phpdoc not inheriting method parameters

Tags: php, phpdoc

In the parent class I have:

```
/**
 * Render the widget.
 * @param  array $options
 * @return string
 */
abstract public function render(array $options=[]);
```

In the child class I have:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function render(array $options=[]) { /*...*/ }
```

But phpdoc gives me the following error for the child class:

```
Argument $options is missing from the Docblock of render()
```

Why?

Edit: if I understand it right at http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/inheritance.html, the method params should be inherited regardless the inheritDoc presence.

Answer (score 1):

@inheritDoc wasn't designed for this purpose.

The {@inheritdoc} inline tag is used in the class DocBlocks of child classes. phpDocumentor will automatically inherit the **@author tag, @version tag, and @copyright** tag from a parent class.

Have a look [here](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.inlineinheritdoc.pkg.html) for official documentation.

Comment: Yes but does it prevent inheritance such as explained here http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/inheritance.html? Method params should be inherited regardless of inheritDoc, no?

Comment: Inheritance of nearly all tags should be expected just via object inheritance.  The inheritdoc inline tag only ever had one purpose -- for you to include the parent's Long Description in a designated spot in the child's docblock.  The tag has no other purpose whatsoever.  Granted, for years I've seen it placed in child docblocks on the expectation that it was necessary for *any* inheritance of docblock info at all.  I fear that some IDEs may have presumed the same and included it in their autotemplating.

Answer (score 0):

> If you do not redeclare the method in the child class, then I think the structure of the various output converters will only show you a list of inherited methods. Some converters will include at least the Short Description of the method from the docblock (HTML:Smarty:PHP), whereas others do not

From the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781222/can-phpdocumentor-phpdoc-display-full-docblocks-for-inherited-methods/7796561#7796561).